# How do I customize HTML headers when doing a POST using AT commands?

Tags: html, c++, c, arduino, at-command

### ADDITIONAL INFO:

I am using an Arduino Nano with the SoftwareSerial library at 9600baud to talk to a (QUECTEL M95 based) GSM2 Click module from Micro Elektronika.  I want to POST data online with custom HTML headers. I can't manage to get the QUECTEL module to POST successfully when I try to add custom headers using the QHTTPPOST command.

This is the first semi-useful guide I found to the HTTP AT commands:
http://www.quectel.com/UploadImage/Downlad/Quectel_WCDMA_UGxx_HTTP_AT_Commands_Manual_V1.2.pdf

Here is the official Command Manual for the QUECTEL M95: http://www.quectel.com/product/prodetail.aspx?id=7

**In Summary:**

1) Registration on network works fine.

2) Posting data when NOT using custom request headers works fine.

3) The QHTTPCFG command is not on the official documentation for this module, but was suggested when contacting the QUECTEL support line.

4) AT Error codes being received: CME ERROR: 3804 "HTTP get no request"

- Mobile operator: Vodacom South Africa
- CSQ Signal Strength: 26

Required format for M95 AT commands:

> Command < CR >

---

### MY CODE

```
//Set the correct URL
mySerial.print("AT+QHTTPURL=34,1\r")
mySerial.print("http://posttestserver.com/post.php\r");
```

RESPONSE:

> OK

```
//Set custom request headers
mySerial.print("AT+QHTTPCFG=\"requestheader\",1\r")
```

RESPONSE:

> OK

```
//Initiate post requst (length 187 characters, 60s to write, 7s to read)
mySerial.print("AT+QHTTPPOST=187,60,7\r");
```

RESPONSE:

> CONNECT

```
//SEND REQUEST HEADER
mySerial.print("POST/post.php HTTP/1.1\r\n");//25 chars
mySerial.print("HOST: posttestserver.com\r\n");//26 chars
mySerial.print("Accept: */*\r\n");//13 chars
mySerial.print("User-Agent: QUECTEL_MODULE2\r\n");//29 chars
mySerial.print("Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n");//24 chars
mySerial.print("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");//49 chars
mySerial.print("Content-Length: 0\r\n");//19 chars
mySerial.print("\r\n");//2 chars
```

... MISSING: After 60 seconds there should be an OK response to indicate successful sending.

```
mySerial.print("AT+QHTTPREAD=5\r");
```

RESPONSE:

> +CME ERROR: 3804

Comment: Where did the `issueCommand` come from?  Why does it not have a `\r` after it (since the `AT+QHTTPPOST....` earlier does include one)? Also, I'm pretty sure this has nothing to do with `c` or `c++`; the `arduino` tag should be sufficient.

Comment: @KevinDTimm My apologies. I meant to replace that with mySerial.print for clarity in the question. I changed my original question. 

issueCommand is just mySerial.print( ) with an \r at the end.

Comment: For me it works, there is a space missing in "POST/post.php"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the AT TCPIP commands instead of the AT HTTP commands I was able to solve my own problem. I have now successfully posted data along with customized headers.

### Here is the code that works:

```
mySerial.print("AT+QIOPEN=\"TCP\",\"64.90.48.15\",80\r");
```

> WAIT for "CONNECT" response

```
mySerial.print("AT+QISEND\r");//
```

> WAIT for ‘>’ response

```
//The HTML Header
mySerial.print("POST /post.php?dir=WPCN HTTP/1.1\r\n");
mySerial.print("HOST: posttestserver.com\r\n");
mySerial.print("Accept: application/json\"\r\n");
mySerial.print("User-Agent: QUECTEL_MODULE2\r\n");
mySerial.print("Content-Length: 7\r\n");
//Signifies end of Header
mySerial.print("\r\n");
//Data:
mySerial.print(“[hello]\r”);
//This is the <CTRL+Z> character which signifies end of transmission
mySerial.print("\x1A");
```

> Response "SEND OK"

```
//End Data Mode
delay(1000);
mySerial.print("+++");
delay(1000);
//Close connection
mySerial.print("AT+QCLOSE\r");
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things that might help:

1. You should wait until de GSM module returns `Connect` to the `mySerial.print("AT+QHTTPPOST=187,60,7\r");` command. After that you should send the post data.
2. When you use the `AT+QHTTP` commands you're using the HTTP layer implemented in the Quectel module. So you only have to send the post data and not the entire TCP message for a POST HTTP. The message you're sending is the TCP packet that implements HTTP protocol. For more information you can take a look of [this](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/webprogramming/HTTP_Basics.html).

From 2, you only need to send the data you want to post. From the link I've added you can see this HTTP POST packet example:

```
POST /bin/login HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Accept: image/gif, image/jpeg, */*
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8000/login.html
Accept-Language: en-us
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)
Content-Length: 37
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache

User=Peter+Lee&pw=123456&action=login
```

If you want to do this POST you should do something like:

```
mySerial.print("AT+QHTTPPOST=37,60,7\r");
```

> CONNECT

```
mySerial.print("User=Peter+Lee&pw=123456&action=login");
```

And then read the response or something.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful thank you. Some comments:

1) The headers in my question are arbitrary. It is just a mock post to test. For the actual application, I have to change the Accept header and add an X-Session_ID header. So, I do need to customize headers.
2) I have managed to post when not customizing the headers.

When delaying after the post request to wait for the CONNECT response, the result is the same: the post fails.

Comment: Your answer is helpful thank you, but it doesn't quite solve the problem yet. 

Some further comments: 

1) The headers in my question are arbitrary. It is just a mock post to test. For the actual application, I have to change the Accept header and add an X-Session_ID header. So, I do need to customize headers. 

2) I have managed to post when not customizing the headers. 

3) When delaying after the QHTTP POST to wait for the CONNECT response, the result is similar: the post fails. I now get 

+CME ERROR: 3825 "InputTimeout"

+CME ERROR: 3804

Comment: The thing is you don't have to put the headers. Headers goes when you're using a TCP connection. When using QHTTPPOST, the Quectel module should be the one that creates the HTTP packet and add the headers.

Comment: So, do you suggest using a TCP command instead for setting the headers? I was under the impression that setting custom headers meant being able to use the post command to change headers, but I get what you're saying.

Comment: In section 3.1.2.1. of the documentation you sent is an example of the using of QHTTPPOST, in it they don't set the headers. I think if you need to set the headers you need to open a TCP connection and send the POST packet over it.

Comment: You are indeed correct. The guy from Quectel steered me in the wrong direction, but I managed to solve the problem as you suggested now. I will post the solution that worked later.